# How to filter with each data inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stored one input value in a variable called `value`.

```
var value=$("#globalSearch").val().trim();
```

And I have object called `jsonData`.

```
0:{name:"xxxx",age:"20",gender:"male"};
1:{name:"yyy",age:"22",gender:"female"};
2:{name:"zzz",age:"20",gender:"female"}
```

Now am filtering the datas only based on `name` and its working fine.

```
 var Data={};
     var value=$("#globalSearch").val().trim();
    $.each(jsonData,function(i,d){
      debugger;
      if(value && d.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())==-1)
      {
        return;
      }

      if(!Data[d.age])
      {
        Data[d.age]=[];
      }

      Data[d.age].push(d);

    });

    return Data
```

Now my question is when I enter input it will check with only with name but I want to check `age and gender also`. How to do it?

I tried like this

```
if(value && d.value&&age&&gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())==-1)
```

It's not working. Please give me any idea.

Comment: so you want to filter the ads which match a specific name, age and gender ?

Comment: @marvel308 yes. can help me?

Comment: also is jsonData an array ? it is unclear

Comment: it is an array.

Comment: `&&` is a logical operator. You need `+` instead with parentheses: `(d.value + d.age + d.gender).toLowerCase()`, and adding an uncommon delimiter would not hurt either.

Comment: age is a number for that,can we use .toLowerCase()?

Comment: Sure, `+` has already converted it to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` is a logical operator. You need a concatenation to happen.

I would suggest to use `join` on the array of elements to perform that concatenation:

```
if(value && 
  [d.value, d.age, d.gender].join('|').toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())==-1)
```

If you have ES6 support, you can do:

```
if(value && 
  !Object.values(d).join('|').toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
```

... which will just concatenate all available values in the `d` object.

Comment: why we need to add .join(|'')

Comment: It is to prevent that a match would cross two values. Imagine someone enters `x2` in the input. Then without the join, but a plain concatenation with `+`, it would match partly with the `value` property (`xxxx`) and partly with the `age` property (`20`). You don't want that (I think). As people will not soon enter a pipe in their search string, it is a suitable character to keep these property values separate in the concatenated string.

Comment: If I give `johnsena` as input,it should return data which matches exactly,if I give  `jo` as input it should return nothing.But in my example I am getting response which are all starts from `jo`.I dont want like this(I want exact match only).Is there any simple wat to do this?

Comment: I have written condition like this `if(value && d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())==-1 && d.age.toLowerCase()!=value.toLowerCase() && d.gender.toLowerCase()!=value.toLowerCase())` its working fine.I want even more simple code to do this condition.

Comment: Sure, but you apply a different rule for the two other fields (not `indexOf`, but `!=`) than you hinted to in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Since you need to check on all 3 filters you can do

1. filter based on name
2. On the result of 1. filter based on age
3. On the result of 2. filter based on gender

Finally you would have an array in which the elements pass all 3 filters